# DOMPDF: files with 0 bytes and text/plain mime-type

Tags: php, mime-types, kohana-3, dompdf, filesize

I'm using Kohana 3 and pdfview/DOMPDF to generate pdf files but they are generated with 0 bytes and text/plain mime-type.

Controller:

```
public function action_pdf() {
    if(isset($_POST['dados'])) {
        $pdf = View_PDF::factory('export/pdf');
        $pdf->title = '';
        $pdf->headers = array();
        $pdf->data = array();

        $this->request->response = $pdf;
        $this->request->send_file(true, 'dados.pdf');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css">
        * {
            border: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        table {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            width: 500px;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Teste</h1>
        <table>
            <tr></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I download the file and open it in epdfview (PDF viewer), it says:

```
Unable to open document
File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported
```

I just don't know what's wrong. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

I downloaded the last beta version and of DOMPDF, deleted the pdfview Kohana's module and did something like that in my controller:

```
public function action_pdf() {
        if(isset($_POST['dados'])) {
            require_once(Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'dompdf/dompdf_config.inc'));

            $view = View::factory('report/pdf');
            $view->title = '';
            $view->data = array();

            $pdf = new DOMPDF();

            $pdf->load_html($view->render());
            $pdf->render();
            $pdf->stream('dados.pdf', array('Attachment' => 1));
        }
    }
```

Now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions? Also try opening the file in an editor to see what the actual content is. You can check if there is an error by calling `$pdfview->render()` before assigning it as the request response.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, and got this "dompdf File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported" message. I checked out the install directions, and it had to do with changing file/folder permissions on the dompdf directory (lib/fonts is what was specifically mentioned in the install instructions). Works now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be work When I changed the folder permission of folder dompdf

```
sudo chmod -rf 777 dompdf
```